# Accessing generic types declared inside interface function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given the following interface:

```
export interface MyInterface<T extends Document> {
    foo<D extends Document>(pipeline?: Document[] | undefined): Promise<D[]>;
}
```

I'm exporting a function that returns the above interface like this:

```
export function makeMyObject<T extends Document>(): MyInterface<T> {
    return {
       async foo<D extends Document>(pipeline) {
            console.log(pipeline);
            const d: D[] = [];
            return Promise.resolve(d);
        }
    };
}
```

However the generic type `D` cannot be used inside the `foo` function.
If I write

```
async foo<D>(pipeline) { ... }
```

Typescript doesn't identify the function declared inside the `MyInterface` interface complaining about the arguments having `any` types.

Is it possible to access the `D` type inside the `foo` function and correctly define the function declared inside `MyInterface`?

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing without being distracted by problems unrelated to your question.  For example, undeclared types like `AggregateOptions` and pseudocode like `...` give us errors you're not asking about.  Please fix those so that we can get started helping.  Thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder because I need `D` to be different from `T` and be defined when `foo` is invoked

Comment: @asant-leitha - Fair enough! :-) Please see jcalz's comment above.

Comment: Re jcalz's comment, is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8BJFNLXAHgBU5RUkATAZzgBEJsBXAW2BQB8cAN4AoOBLjoIESmzogGLdp178YAgBRgEYYABtkwAPwAuFdz4oA2gF04AHzhcmwdEcYBKcwAUoEHgRmYDk7AQBuUQBfUVFQSFgpF2wYBAgkOB5MAGtgIgB5ACMAK2AUmgUlVg5LdS1vAhIyDBwQ6iExSTgoYBguKAzOrolMZkIkbCkZOUr+ZRq1QW1dAyNPEXFhrex05gh9YAA6fQgAc2W9QyRgT0it7d34RnM2OzgAXjg7O-uunr6BnA-AEgkcent9AA3YCaLw-LYxLpRSJRIA) the problem you're having? (Note how I've removed most of the seemingly-irrelevant stuff.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder exactly that

Comment: @asant-leitha - Please edit your question accordingly. I've done most of the work for you already.

Comment: Why is `T` in this question at all? It seems to be completely unused. If it serves a purpose for the question, please [edit] the code to make it obvious.  If not, please [edit] to remove it.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that your issue can be demonstrated via [the code in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wR1pQW).  You want to be able to "partially annotate" a generic function call signature, but it seems that this doesn't work.  Is that right?  If so then please [edit] the question to focus on the above [mre] or something quite like it.

Comment: @jcalz I did edit the question with the code of the first playground which is exactly the problem I am having

Comment: Okay then I guess someone else can help further, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you have no reason to use any generics in your function, since you're not using the generic in any of the parameters.

So these are equivalent

```
export interface MyInterface<T extends Document> {
    foo<D extends Document>(pipeline?: Document[] | undefined): Promise<D[]>;
}

export interface MyInterface {
    foo(pipeline?: Document[] | undefined): Promise<Document[]>;
}
```

Basically, you only want to use generics when you're trying to infer something directly from the parameters, otherwise they're useless.

Perhaps you were trying to do this?

```
export function makeMyObject<T extends Document>(options: {
    parameter: T[]
}) {
    return {
       async foo(pipeline?: Document[]): Promise<T[]> {
            console.log(pipeline);
            const d: T[] = [];
            return Promise.resolve(d);
        }
    };
}
```

If you're trying to infer the foo result type from the makeMyObject parameters.

Or if you're trying to infer from the foo parameter type, then simply do

```
async foo<D extends Document>(pipeline?: D[]): Promise<D[]> {
    console.log(pipeline);
    const d: D[] = []; // Using D[] is allowed here
    return Promise.resolve(d);
}
```